# Has anybody gotten flutter universal links with uni_links working on iOS 13?

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-universal-links

I swear everything was working fine a few months ago.
And then I picked up developing my app again lately and now I can't get universal links working on ios. Android is fine, but no luck on ios. Not sure if it's the latest flutter, the latest uni_links or the latest ios. But I just can't get it working properly on ios.

Yes, I updated the my `apple-app-site-association` to include the new recommended format (and keep the old one there are well), like:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "Z1239YU75.com.mycomp.mysubdomain",
                "paths": [ "/mysubdomain.mycomp.com/*" ],
                "appIDs": ["Z1239YU75.com.mycomp.mysubdomain"],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/mysubdomain.mycomp.com/*"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

(and I can curl my subdomain and the file is serverd properly, no redirect)

My `Runner.entitlements` looks correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks: mysubdomain.mycomp.com </string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I just can't get it to work. I tried on the simu, on the phone, with testflight... nothing works on ios, it keeps opening in safari (and android works properly...)

This is what I tried on the simu if you are curious: `xcrun simctl openurl booted 'https://mysubdomain.mycomp.com/abcd'`

In case you asked, here is `flutter doctor`:

```
>> flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021, locale es-ES)
    • Flutter version 1.20.3 at /Users/didier/tmp/flutter
    • Framework revision 216dee60c0 (hace 2 semanas), 2020-09-01 12:24:47 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/didier/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/didier/Library/Android/sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Users/didier/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.7)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.7, Build version 11E801a
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.2.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 49.0.4
    • Dart plugin version 202.7206

[✓] VS Code (version 1.39.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.4.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 (mobile) • CF71C2E0-11E3-44D2-A1B0-45CCBDF9B84C • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-7 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: I have the exact same question... So, did you solve it?

Comment: Have you added: `
    <key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key>
    <true/>` to your Info.plist? Here are the docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking for me this opens the app but i'm stuck on figuring out how to navigate to the page in the app after the link opens.

Comment: hey guys, sorry it took me forever to reply here, but yes, I did get it working. A few thing to be aware of: the webserver which server the `apple-app-site-association` file needs to set the proper mime-type (`application/json`). Also, in my latest version, I am using this: `{ "appID": "123449YU75.com.mycomp.mysubdomain", "paths": [ "*" ], "appIDs": ["123449YU75.mycomp.mysubdomain"], "components": [ { "/": "*" } ] }`

Answer (score 2):

If you need  your `apple-app-site-association` to support the entire website, you need to set `*`. With /{path_name}/* configured, this specifies a specific section of your website. More details can be read on the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html). You also need to [configure](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking#enable-deep-linking-on-ios) your deep link on the iOS app's Info.plist